# Flutter apk not installing in some phones

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The apk is working in fine most of the android phones. But when I try to install in Moto E4 plus, I got this issue
[image]

I created androidX flutter project.
project configuration.
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28

What can be the issue?

Comment: Do you have any `<uses-feature>` in your manifest? also some library may add to your manifest when building.

Comment: No. There is no <uses-feature> in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Are there any dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml` file ?

Comment: pinput: 0.1.10
  provider: ^3.1.0+1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+1
  pin_code_text_field: ^1.5.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^3.4.4895
  intl: ^0.16.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+1
  image_cropper: ^1.2.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
  flutter_typeahead: ^1.8.0
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.3+5
  http: ^0.12.0+4